# Best way to Array Object along curve

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, dupli-groups

I'm currently trying to create objects along a curve at a set distance to each other (or distributed by the count). All while taking the position and rotation on the curve into consideration but not bending and distorting it (I'm looking at you curve modifier)

My solution so far is:

Create a curve that serves as a path to follow.

Create a plane and make it tiny in scale. Put an array modifier onto the plane 
and afterwards a curve modifier so the planes follow the curve.

After that I check the duplication option in the object tab of the plane and set it to faces.

Then make the plane parent of the object that I want to get duplicated.

[image: Example Setup]

This kind of works but has a few downfalls, as far as I know until now:

1. The plane has to be tiny so it vanishes in the object I want to duplicate. If it's not setup like this and you hide the plane, the object that got duplicated will be hidden too.
2. You can't hide the "original" object, so you basically have it sitting at 0,0,0 all the time, which is quiet annoying as you can see it most of the time in my scene
3. It's not that easy to control.

I know I could make the duplicates real and adjust them, but I need the scene to be easily changeable later on (as the count and distance could change)

So the question would be: Does anybody know a better solution for this problem?

I know this can be easily done in C4D using cloner and things like that, but in blender?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers
Daniel

Comment: I don't quite see the reason to use Curve modifier if you use duplifaces (or dupliverts). Parent object to curve, enable duplication in curve settings and that's enough. You can convert curve to mesh and adjust its amount of vertices afterwards. It's not clear as well why leaving original object at 0,0,0 - move it together with the curve somewhere (or move the curve as the object is parented). Other than that no reliable way to avoid distortion of arrayed object if using Curve modifier, it might be tiny but present

Comment: Hello, 
yes of course that works (after converting the curve to mesh, before that nothing happens if I parent it) 
Though this is not what I'm looking for. I need the flexibility to change the path and see the elements on it and change the distances between the elements easily. Therefore converting it and having to manually subdividing it, guessing the distances isn't really working out for me :)
I know Blender is not C4D but I wonder if there's no easier way that keeps the flexibility.

Comment: You can use [dupliframes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/duplication/dupliframes.html), object doesn't have to be of mesh type, the thing is to disable Speed which is used for traveling along a path, then it will be duplicated along a path. Afaik the only workable way to distribute dupli objects along a curve object.